# How can I insert data with factories in a one-to-many relationship?

Tags: php, laravel

My first code that is working correctly:
. In the databaseSeeder seeder

```
    Department::factory()->count(3)
            ->has(Course::factory()->count(4))
            ->has(Discipline::factory()->count(5))
            ->has(Professor::factory()->count(5))
            ->create();
```

```
    Class::factory()
            ->count(3)
            ->for(Course::factory()->state([
                 'name' => 'what i need to select in the course table just exist with data',
            ]))
            ->create();
```

I want to know how to make work the second code without creating new Course.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try directly adding it to the first code like :

```
Department::factory()->count(3)
        ->has(Course::factory()
              ->has(Class::factory()->count(3)
          )->count(4))
        ->has(Discipline::factory()->count(5))
        ->has(Professor::factory()->count(5))
        ->create();
```